# Prove $\det(A+I)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Need help with my homework.

$A \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ is upper-triangular and  $A^{n}=0$

Please hint how to prove, that $\det(A+I)=1$

I dont know how it do, know laplace equation

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the determinant of an upper triangular matrix?  What is the $i$-th diagonal entry of $T^p$ for a triangular matrix $T$? What can you conclude about the diagonal entries of $A$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Show that for an upper triangular matrix $A$, if one entry on the main diagonal is non-zero then $A^n$ is never the zero matrix (hint: split the matrix as $D+T$ where $D$ is diagonal and $T$ is strictly upper triangular).

2) Conclude that for the given $A$ the main diagonal consists of zeros only.

3) What form does $A+I$ have then? What is the determinant?

Comment: I dont understand what mean that the $A^n=0$

Comment: You wrote $A^n=0$ in your own question. Do you not know what that means?

Comment: yea, I dont know what mean the $A^n = 0 $ in this exercise

Comment: A times itself n times equals the zero matrix